# sql calculate delta between the column value for one day and the previous day

Tags: sql, datetime, delta

I have a query like this:

```
;WITH A AS (SELECT * FROM T1 where T1.targetDate=@inputdate), 
      B AS (SELECT A.*, T2.SId, T2.Type, T2.Value
            FROM A 
            INNER JOIN T2 ON A.SId = T2.SId )
SELECT A.*, B.Type, B.Value 
FROM B
```

My question is, instead of getting the `Value` for `@inputdate,` how to get the delta of `Value` between `@inputdate` and the previous day `(DATEADD(day, -1, @inputdate ))`?

**Edited**:

Sorry for not being clear, the 'Value' is of type int. For example, if `@inputdate = '20130708'`, the `Value` for '20130708' is 30, and the 'Value' for previous day '20130707' is 20, so it should return (30 - 20) which is 10.

Comment: **Please add Schema**. What are the columns that have 20 and 30? you are using 2 different tables, `CTE A` uses table `T1`, `CTE B` uses table `T2`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, and assuming that Value is DATE format

```
;WITH A AS (SELECT * FROM T1 where T1.targetDate=@inputdate), 
      B AS (SELECT A.*, T2.SId, T2.Type, T2.Value
            FROM A 
            INNER JOIN T2 on A.SId = T2.SId )
SELECT A.*, T2.Type, T2.Value, DATEDIFF(DAY, b.Value, DATEDADD(DAY, -1,@InputDate)) AS Delta
FROM B
```

Comment: Edited, I forgot to add `DATEADD(day, -1 @InpuDate)`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear,  the 'Value' is of type int. I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have a stock prices table: which has the symbol, date and closing prices etc, you could use something like this:

```
select symb, ret_dt, close, (close-(lead(close,1) over (partition by symb order by ret_dt desc,close)))as difference, (lead(close,1) over 
(partition by symb order by ret_dt desc,close)) as lead
from stocks.nyse2010;
```

**Note:** here `ret_dt` is the date, close is the closing price and I have added an additional lead column for representational purposes.